# Upgrades for the TRS-80 Model 100 portable

Tags: hardware, hardware-mods, trs-80-model-100

The [TRS-80 Model 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80_Model_100) portable officially allowed for RAM expansion to 32k and an external acoustic coupler for the model. What other upgrades and peripherals exist for the Model 100? I had one of these second hand, and they have great battery life and true portability (about 3 lb) unlike most of the 80s *portables* which [weighed 16](http://lowendmac.com/1989/mac-portable/) or [even 28 lb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compaq_Portable)!

Comment: Are you only interested in the original official stuff, or are you also looking for modern hacks, upgrades, etc?  The resulting answer is pretty much going to just be a list of things.  Are there any specific features you are missing on it that you would like or any task you are trying to do that it can't currently?

Comment: Weird! I watched Dave's EEVblog teardown of one of these just yesterday! He said you could get a number of tech manuals: yep! See https://www.eevblog.com/2010/10/05/eevblog-116-retro-notebook-teardown-tandy-model-100/

Comment: The YouTube clip is here: http://youtu.be/Prl6D7bqQo8

Comment: I would be interested in both the official stuff and modern hacks to add new capacities to the Model 100. I sold by TRS-80 Model 100 but I've upgraded my IIgs with both standard upgrades like 1 meg of additional RAM http://whatisthe2gs.apple2.org.za/apple-1meg-ram-expansion and more modern cards like a flashram hard disk http://whatisthe2gs.apple2.org.za/microdrive-ide .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mentioned, you could upgrade TRS-80 Model 100's RAM to 32k.  You can also get a [REX](http://bitchin100.com/wiki/index.php?title=REX) chip, which uses the ROM expansion slot to provide additional flash memory.

The TRS-80 Model 100 had several peripherals available (in addition to the acoustic coupler) including a cassette recorder, an external drive, a barcode reader, printers, and even a "Disk/Video Interface" that allowed you to connect up to two 184k disk drives and a TV or video monitor...
[image]

You could even use a "null modem" to connect the 100 to other TRS-80 computers to transfer files.

Here's a [link to the user manual](ftp://ftp.whtech.com/club100/doc/TRS80-M100-User-Guide.pdf).  The peripheral connection guidelines are in Appendix A.

Comment: I used a serial cable to connect the TRS-80 Model 100 to my PowerMac G3 233 using the ClarisWorks terminal module to talk to the TRS-80. The TRS-80 manual explains how to transfer programs over the serial cable from another computer.

Comment: In reference to the peripheral above, I have a Disk Video Interface box that's in nice shape that I'd love to get to a good home. Before they were discontinued in the 1980's, they were sold pretty cheap and I couldn't resist.

Comment: @jwettroth I'd totally take that off your hands, but I'm not sure my Model 100 will ever run again.

Comment: @jwettroth If you still have it and the offer still stands, I would be very interested in giving your DVI a good home (see profile for contact info).